# Which OAuth2 grant to use when dealing with a web based front-end

Tags: django, oauth-2.0

I have a backend running Django 1.7 and a front-end developed separately with Bootstrap. The front-end talks to the backend through a REST API that I want to protect with OAuth2.

The question is: which grant type should I use? I trust the people working on the front-end but it does not mean I trust Javascript :-) I can't decide whether I should choose the Implicit grant or the Resource owner password-based.

Any experienced advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Especially when working with an API that is not on the same domain or server as your front end, it's usually better to use something like the web application flow for OAuth 2. This is typically referred to as the [implicit grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.2), and uses the `grant_type` of `token`.

This way you won't need to worry about sending credentials across the wire, like you would need to for the [resource owner password credentials grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.3). Along the same lines, you also don't have to deal with hiding private keys for the [authorization code grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1).

With the implicit grant, only the OAuth token must be stored on the local machine. This should  be better, as the token should be able to be revoked quickly in the event that the token become public or something else forces it to be invalidated. The user should be logged in on the API server when the authorization request is made, but most OAuth providers support a custom login page that can be used as well.

With the password credentials grant, both the username and password must be stored on the local machine which requires you to additionally secure them. They are also considerably more difficult to revoke if the need arises.

Comment: I just don't understand how I can distinguish 2 different users in that type of grant (implicit). At no point the end-user is asked to provide his/her credentials (username and password), so how do I use implicit grant to protect an API endpoint such as `example.com/api/account-details/`?

Comment: With an implicit grant, the client (API consumer, mobile app for instance) should send the user (mobile app user) to your website, displaying the authorization page in the browser. Once the user logs in and authorizes the application, the app will get the access token to use.

Comment: So this works if and only if the Authorization endpoint (exposed by the OAuth2 server) requires a regular authentication such as the permission class `rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated` in DRF. In this way the user that lands on the authorization endpoint **must** log in before granting access to the client. However, is it always the case (that the auth endpoint requires authentication, especially in `django-oauth-toolkit`)? How does the authentication mechanism work when we have the `OAuth2Backend` setup in Django?

Comment: The whole point being that I want to get rid of the default session authentication because I am working on different domains for the front-end and the back-end.

Comment: [Lets move this conversation into the chat.](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67484/conversation-between-kevin-brown-and-buddyshot)